# Dynamically changing the viewport in iOS Safari doesn't work until the second time rotating the device

Tags: javascript, ios, safari, scale, viewport

I'm developing a web for iPad/iPhone and need to set different viewports for portrait and landscape mode. I'm doing this with Javascript with the orientationchange event, but there is a problem, after loading the page when I first rotate the device, the content doesn't get scaled, but this is only the first time, if I go back to the first state and then rotate back again, this time works perfectly.
I tried the same but loading the page with the other orientation and it's the same problem, it only scales the content properly after the second try.